# Perform some operation when a foreach will break

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I'm trying to implement the IEnumerable interface for one of my class:

```
public class NdbScanTableTuple<TKey,TRow> : NdbTableTuple<TKey,TRow>,IEnumerable<TRow>
{
   public IEnumerator<TRow> GetEnumerator()
    {
        yieldTransaction = StartTransaction();
        NdbScanOperation scanPub = yieldTransaction.ScanTable(m_scanRow.NdbRecordValue,           NdbOperation.LockMode.LM_Read);

        //some error checking in the middle... and than the loop
        TRow tmpRes;
        while (scanPub.nextResult<TRow>(ref m_scanRow.ManagedRow) == 0)
        {
            tmpRes = m_scanRow.GetValue();
            yield return tmpRes;
        }           
        yieldTransaction.Close();

    }

    public void CloseYieldedTransaction() 
    {
        yieldTransaction.Close();
    }

}
```

i use the code in this way:
            NdbScanTableTuple m_protoTable;

```
        //init and some other things...

        foreach (protoprocRow proto in m_protoTable) 
        {
            if (proto.col_name == protoprocName) 
            {
                m_protoStruct = proto;
                m_protoTable.CloseYieldedTransaction();
                break;
            }
        }
```

This because i MUST close the transaction when i exit from the loop.
Now my question is: there is a way to execute the `yieldTransaction.Close()` without calling the `CloseYieldedTransaction()` explicitly when i prematurely terminate the foreach loop?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question completely but maybe:

    try {
        foreach ...
    } finally {
        close...
    }

Comment: This is not how to implement `IEnumerable<TRow>`. Your `GetEnumerator()` needs to return `IEnumerator<TRow>`, but you're not doing that. You're treating `GetEnumerator()` as though it returns `IEnumerable<T>` and not `IEnumerator<TRow>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement `IEnumerator<T>` like this:

```
public class NdbScanTableTuple<TKey,TRow> : IEnumerable<TRow>
{
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IEnumerator<TRow> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new Enumerator<TRow>();
    }

    private class Enumerator<T> : IEnumerator<T>
    {
        object IEnumerator.Current { get { return this.Current; } }
        public T Current { get { return tmpRes; } }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            yieldTransaction.Close();
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

(I've left a bit of the detail for you.)

That's why it's not working.

You'll notice that `Dispose` will do the clean up for you naturally.

Comment: Really, i don't understand why the yield operator should not work, according to the doc:
[MSDN yield Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) BTW i implemented the IDisposable interface in the Transaction class and used the `using` statement

Comment: @SalvatoreSorbello - Thanks for the link. I didn't realize that `IEnumerator<T>` could perform yield operations directly. Nevertheless I think you'll find that to close your connection you'll need to implement the `IEnumerator<T>` interface as per my answer to make it work.

Comment: There is no doubt your answer is the best one and let do the things in the right way, i was hoping there was a faster way to do it

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use the [iterator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscyy5s0.aspx) style of function, you should actually create a (possibly nested) class that implements the [`IEnumerator<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface and contains the required resources to perform iteration (such as your transaction object).

That class can then contain the transaction object and `Close` it from within the iterator's `Dispose` method which is automatically called when the `foreach` terminates (whether normally or abnormally).

This will also make your design cleaner since at the moment, it appears that your storing the transaction as a member of the class, which makes your current class unsafe for multiple threads to enumerate (or even for a single thread to obtain multiple enumerators).

Comment: I think i got your point, so you suggest something like this:
create a method inside my class that give me back an IEnumerable<TRow>,IDisposable object(the nested class you talk about), in this way i can: 1)put the transation.close in the dispose method and,2) (Very important i was not paying so much attention in this) allow multiple iterators with different transaction instances

Comment: `yield return/break` supports `Dispose` too - see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have no idea the enumeration was stopped. The method simply isn't called anymore, but you can't know that.

A way to ensure the transaction is closed would be to use `IDisposable` in a `using` statement, and the proper finalizer in the place where the native resources (most likely sockets - you don't have to handle that, it's already handled) are. The tricky part is you really can't rely on any managed resources still being there in a finalizer, so you have a problem.

When you are using `IDisposable`, `foreach` will call `Dispose` when it's going out of scope, so that's good. Of course, when you're not using a `foreach`, many of the automated things fall apart.

Now, `yield return` makes it's own `IEnumerator`. However, it *does* handle disposal properly. The only thing you have to do is something you should always do: use `try - finally`:

```
public IEnumerator<TRow> GetEnumerator()
{
  var yieldTransaction = StartTransaction();

  try
  {
    NdbScanOperation scanPub = yieldTransaction.ScanTable
       (m_scanRow.NdbRecordValue, NdbOperation.LockMode.LM_Read);

    //some error checking in the middle... and than the loop
    TRow tmpRes;
    while (scanPub.nextResult<TRow>(ref m_scanRow.ManagedRow) == 0)
    {
      tmpRes = m_scanRow.GetValue();
      yield return tmpRes;
    }           
  }
  finally
  {
    yieldTransaction.Close();
  }
}
```

Learn to use `finally` - every managed finalization you're doing should be in `finally`, it's quite critical for proper in-depth exception handling.

Comment: So, if i use the break in the foreach loop the finally block will called anyway?Are you sure?

Comment: @SalvatoreSorbello Yes, it will. Just make sure that you're using `foreach` when enumerating - if you're iterating over the enumerator manually, you have to handle the `Dispose` call manually as well.